# Spaces to tabs converter

Tags: beginner, c, formatting

I wrote a program to convert spaces to tabs. If there are 4 spaces it should convert them to tab. Please let me know how to improve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TABVALUE 4
int c, d, s;

int main(void) {
    c = s = d = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            s++;
            for (int j = 0; j < TABVALUE - 1; j++) {
                d = getchar();
                if (d == ' ') {
                    s++;
                }
            }
            if (s == TABVALUE) {
                putchar('\t');
                s = 0;
            }
        } else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/143110/9357)

Answer (score 3):

- **Bugs**

  `j` unconditionally loops to `TABVALUE` - 1. This is wrong:

  - If `d` happens to *not* be a space, it is not printed out.
  - If next `d` happens to be a space, it is still counted.

  Test against `a  b  cdef`. The output is `a\tf`.

Comment: Yes, i noticed that too.But couldnt solve.Do you know how would i solve that ??

Comment: Rewrite the inner loop as `while ((c = getchar()) == ' ')`. Count spaces and break the loop at right time. Print either spaces or a tab. _Only then_ print `c`. Care about special cases (newline for example).

Comment: @MuhamedCicak Is this supposed to be K&R Exercise 1-21? It's rather tricky to implement correctly. See examples [1](/q/9000/9357) and [2](/q/51702/9357).

Comment: @200_success Thanks for the nice examples :)